# Query/Flatten all the elemensts inside array in nested Json in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am new to snowflake. I am tyring to query/flatten all the fields inside nested Json but in Transactio array, i have multiple transactions and i can't extract all of them, i can only select the first using indexing.

My json structure is like this

```
[
  {
    "Employee": {
      "UID": "value",
      "Transactions": [
        {
          "ORBIS-Tx-ID": "123F",
          "ReferenceID": {
            "Amount": {
              "Charge": 0.3,
              "Currency": "USD",
              "StatusEntry": {
                "Status": "COMPLETED",
                "Timestamp": {
                  "$date": "2021-09-07T11:58:40.672Z"
                }
              },
              "SummaryStatus": "COMPLETED",
              "Value": 9.7
            },
            "Metadata": {
              "Notes": "Salary advance paid out",
              "TxSubType": {
                "From": {
                  "OrbisUID": "OPA",
                  "ProviderID": "gbQG0sTWZVmioQ"
                },
                "To": {
                  "UID": "59B7",
                  "ProviderID": "DnYOEs5A"
                }
              },
              "TxType": "ADVANCE"
            },
            "OrigMessage": {
              "EC": "0",
              "SC": 200,
              "approvalCode": "145382",
              "card": {
                "expirationDate": "202605",
                "last4": "6423"
              },
              "fees": {
                "interchange": "0.10",
                "network": "0.01"
              },
              "network": "VisaFF",
              "networkID": "5812198027",
              "networkRC": "00",
            },
            "Provider": {
              "ProviderID": "iuMVYeZLHQ",
              "ProviderName": "Name"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "ORBIS-Tx-ID": "123F",
          "ReferenceID": {
            "Amount": {
              "Charge": 0.45,
              "Currency": "USD",
              "StatusEntry": {
                "Status": "COMPLETED",
                "Timestamp": {
                  "$date": "2021-09-10T15:44:11.896Z"
                }
              },
              "SummaryStatus": "COMPLETED",
              "Value": 19.55
            },
            "Metadata": {
              "Notes": "Salary advance paid out",
              "TxSubType": {
                "From": {
                  "OrbisUID": "ORA",
                  "ProviderID": “QIHVsTWZVmioQ"
                },
                "To": {
                  "UID": "59EB11-85A9-00155DC29747",
                  "ProviderID": "DngXSCgkYOEs5A"
                }
              },
              "TxType": "ADVANCE"
            },
            "OrigMessage": {
              "EC": "0",
              "SC": 200,
              "approvalCode": "164647",
              "card": {
                "expirationDate": "202605",
                "last4": "6423"
              },
              "fees": {
                "interchange": "0.10",
                "network": "0.02",
              },
              "network": "VisaFF",
              "networkID": "58112122",
              "networkRC": "00"
            },
            "Provider": {
              "ProviderID": "QjS0o4Mg",
              "ProviderName": "Name"
            }
          }
        }
          }
        }
        ]
```

I want to have all the fields in separate columns and be able to query for eg. Charge inside Transactions.ReferenceID.Amount for all the transactions.
For now i am flattening like this:

```
select 
    value:Employer:UID as ER_ORBISUID,
    value:Employee:UID EE_ORBISUID,
    value:Employee:Transactions[0]['ORBIS-Tx-ID'] as TrasactionID,
    array_size(value:Employee:Transactions) as arraySize,
    value:Employee:Transactions[0].ReferenceID.Amount.Charge as AmtValue
    ,value:Employee:Transactions[0]:ReferenceID.Amount.StatusEntry.Status as Staus
from test11,
   -- lateral flatten(input => CLMN) as aa,
    lateral flatten(input => CLMN:Employee:Transactions);
```

When i run the above query, i am only able to get the first element inside the array as i am using 0 index, i am not sure how to do it without using index. Anyone can help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (LATERAL) FLATTEN function to extract a nested variant, object, or array from JSON data.

Details & Example: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Using-lateral-flatten-to-extract-data-from-JSON-internal-field